# Semi-circle on the bottom side of a div?

Tags: html, css, border

I need a semi-circle for the bottom border of a div (not rounded corners), like this.

[image]

This is the div code:

```
#navlogo img {
position:fixed;
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
z-index: 2;
left:45%;
top:0;
background-color:#CCC;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**border-radius does the trick, sorry for not wording it better**

Comment: Do you mean "not rounded corners" in the visual sense or the "I don't want to use `border-radius`" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need `border-bottom-left-radius: 50%` and `border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;`.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ufar4mrj/

Comment: OP *specifically* said "not rounded corners"

Comment: @TylerH "not rounded corners" doesn't always translate to "not `border-radius`". We can only know by asking the OP.

Comment: @BDawg true, what OP meant could have been something else, but this answer literally rounded the corners, which the OP explicitly mentioned wanting to avoid. It seems OP was simply mistaken, though, based on the accept.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, I think the OP just meant the result should not look like rounded corners. Funny how interpretation can completely change an answer sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are only few ways to include rounded shapes in a webpage:

- border-radius (rounded corners)
- images
- SVG
- Flash

Considering what you want to do, SVG and Flash are out of question, leaving only images and rounded corners to you. I don't know why you refuse to use border-radius because it works very well. You won't find anything that integrates better into a webpage.